# How to clean up the main Express file?

Tags: node.js

Ok, I have this server.js file.
Inside of it, I have all the requires, including Express itself.

In the client side, I can just create any file, do whaterever I want and import it on the main file:

```
<script src='path'></script>
```

But how can I do that on the server side? I'm using some module.exports to my Mongoose Models, like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserModel);
```

I'm trying to use it to insert my HTTP requests into separate files. For example, I've tried to use module.exports on this:

```
app.get('/ticket/messages/:ticketID', function(req, res){
TicketMsgModel.find({ fatherID: req.params.ticketID },
    function(err, obj){
        res.json(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: Read about modules and `require()` in Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create routes in separate files and then include them:

**userRoutues.js**

```
var router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/url", function() {...});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
app.use("/user", require("userRoutes"));
```

This means that for all incoming requests to `/url` express will use routes defined in `userRoutes.js` file